# Cardview Elevation set diff for Top ,bottom,left and right

Tags: android, android-cardview

how to set Elevation value 2dp Right, 2dp Left, 1dp Top and 1dp Bottom

i used below code and its just give common Elevation for all side

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look for design guidelines before try to do it because I think it is not advisable to do in that manner:

https://material.google.com/components/cards.html#cards-content